# SQL: LIKE vs = bug?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a very strange behaviour that I cannot understand in my SQL DB (I am using MySQL 5.5.8):

I have in a table a varchar(10) a name: joe.

If a run a sql like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM `names` WHERE `name` = 'joe '
```

I get one result: joe but this is wrong since in the table I do not have any 'joe ' (with a space at the end. I only have 'joe' (no space)

However if I execute:

```
SELECT ID FROM `names` WHERE `name` LIKE 'joe '
```

I get as I expect: nothing.
As far as I know = should be "exact" matching while like is more loose to be able to use it with sub strings and %.

What am I missing ?

Comment: This is how it's designed.  It's in the docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: how is this a duplicate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Trailing spaces are not significant for `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` comparison using `=`. See [string comparison functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html):

> In particular, trailing spaces are significant, which is not true for CHAR or VARCHAR comparisons performed with the = operator:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT 'a' = 'a ', 'a' LIKE 'a ';
> +------------+---------------+
> | 'a' = 'a ' | 'a' LIKE 'a ' |
> +------------+---------------+
> |          1 |             0 |
> +------------+---------------+
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the response I checked the documentation and you are perfectly right, although it seems a bit strange to me :) but as long as is documented ... :) it is a feature not a bug

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because of the data type you are using.

> The CHAR and VARCHAR types are similar, but differ in the way they are
>   stored and retrieved. As of MySQL 5.0.3, they also differ in maximum
>   length and in whether trailing spaces are retained.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html